# better display in term (/bin/bash) or multi-term (multi-term.el) in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

when I use term inside emacs ( M-x term), I found that if I maximize the window, then the display in quite good (when I am doing something like apt-get install full-texlive or something will give me a lot of message). But if I resize the Emacs window or the size is not maximal when I open Emacs, then the display is very awful.....(when there are a lot of message in the terminal); But if I use terminal directly (not run in emacs), the display is very well however I resize it (maximal or not maximal), it adjust the output display.
I would like to know if there is a way to improve the display of term inside emacs.

Comment: the display annoy me especially when I want to use up key to use the commands I have typed before

Comment: The term in English is usually "maximize," not "maximal."  "I maximized the window."  "The window was not maximized."

Comment: You have to be more specific about the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for a way to keep long lines from wrapping.

Try

```
M-x toggle-truncate-lines
```

Also very useful for shell mode (not term) is to make emacs interpret ANSI codes:

```
M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-off
```